# DISCOUNT with multiple criteria in Power BI

Tags: if-statement, powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I have two tables are Data and Report.

Data Table: In the Data table, two columns are Item, Qty, and Order. The Item columns contain as a text & number and qty and number column stored as text and number.

The item column is repeated according to the order and the same item column contains two different qty according to the order column.

Report Table:

I have a unique item column.

Data and Report file looks like.

Data

ITEM    QTY ORDER
123 200 1
123 210 0
5678    220 1
5678    230 0
5555    240 1
6666    250 1
9876    260 1
2345    270 1
901 280 1
901 280 1
902 300 1
902 300 1
123456  200 1
123456  200 1
123456  210 1
123456  210 1
123456  0   1
567 200 1
567 210 1
567 210 1
567 0   1
453 5000    1
453 5000    1
453 5000    1
453 5000    1
112 5000    1
112 5000    1
112 5000    1
112 5000    1
116 5000    1
116 5001    1
116 0   1
116 0   1
116 5000    0
116 5001    0
116 0   0
116 0   0

Report

ITEM    DESIRED RESULT (QTY)
123 200
5678    220
5555    240
6666    250
9876    260
2345    270
901 280
902 300
123456  MIXED
567 MIXED
4444    NA
12  NA
10  NA
453 5000
112 5000
116 MIXED
Expand snippet
Desired Result

I would like to pull the qty against the order “1” from the data table into the report table according to the item.

If the item is found in the data table then return the qty in the report table according to the item. {Please refer to the “Data” and “Report table for item 123 and 5678 etc….}

If an item is not found in the data table then return “NA” in the report table according to the item. {Please refer to the “Data” and “Report table for item 10, 12,444}

The same item contains two different qty then returns as a text “Mixed” in the report table according to the item. {Please refer to the “Data” and “Report table for item 123456,116 & 567}

Currently I am using the following calculated column CURRENT DAX FOR QTY = LOOKUPVALUE(DATA[QTY],DATA[ITEM],'DESIRED RESULT'[ITEM],DATA[ORDER],1,"NA") enter image description here

It’s almost working fine but it’s giving the wrong result “NA” were two different qty for the same item & two different order (0,1) or (1) or (o) {Please refer to the “Data” and “Report table for item 123456, 116 & 567} but the desired result is “Mixed” those three items.

Note: I convert the qty column from number to text otherwise it gives an error, is there any alternative option to achieve my result.

Herewith attached the PBI file for your reference https://www.dropbox.com/s/hf40q27pvn3ij2g/DAX-LOOKUPVALUE%20FILTER%20BY.pbix?dl=0.

Comment: Is it correct to say that you would get the same result if the `DATA[ORDER] = 0` rows were deleted?

Comment: But I want keep the record in my data table. Can you please advise how can I achieve my output either in my exciting calculated column or new calculated column. Can you please advise.

Comment: That's fine. I just wanted to check that those rows could be ignored for this calculated column.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding correctly, this can be done with the method I [suggested previously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66111490/lookup-value-with-multiple-scenario-in-power-bi/66121245#66121245) with the addition of a filter for `DATA[ORDER] = 1`.

```
IF (
    CALCULATE ( DISTINCTCOUNT ( DATA[QTY] ), DATA[ORDER] = 1 ) > 1,
    "MIXED",
    CALCULATE ( SELECTEDVALUE ( DATA[QTY], "NA" ), DATA[ORDER] = 1 )
)
```

Comment: Thanks for advise and solution. It's working well. Can you please explain why the item columns (both tables) are not referring in your calculated column. How do we ensuing it will pick actual qty according to the item.

Comment: IF (
    CALCULATE ( DISTINCTCOUNT ( DATA[QTY] ), DATA[ORDER] = 1 ) > 1,
    "MIXED",
    CALCULATE ( SELECTEDVALUE ( DATA[QTY], "NA" ), DATA[ORDER] = 1 )
)
 The above mentioned function need to be added in my exiting calculated column can you please advise.

Comment: ITEM is implicitly included as a filter after the row [context transition](https://www.sqlbi.com/articles/understanding-context-transition/) and propagated across the relationship. The DAX I gave is what you should replace your LOOKUPVALUE.... with.

Comment: thanks for conformation. thanks for conformation. I try to apply your logic into my example/sample table and real data, I got two different error message one is "circular dependency the column and another given all of them as a "Mixed".

Comment: The above mentioned solution it's hard to understand for power bi new learner. Can you please advise is there any alternative I can achieve the result? The requirement is look like simple but it's very complex in power bi. I happy to maintain any duplication column in my data table or in report table. can you please advise when you have time.

Comment: I don't think you can get it much simpler and still be functional. I tested it in the PBIX you attached and it worked fine for me, so I can't reproduce the error.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply and advice. I am received error at my end. I don't why? Much appreciated your time and help and sorry for inconvenience.